# Laravel - unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

Hi i am trying to set a a test to test my database calls. I want to pass a variables in url but cant seem to get it to work.

I wanted to do this

```
public function testDb()
{
               $response = $this->call('GET', '/searchAvailability?keyword=test product');
               $content =    $response->getContent();

           $this->assertEquals('[{"name":"test product"}]',$content );
}
```

But i keep getting "Undefined variable : keyword" when i try. It works in the browser just not when i run phpunit. Anyone got any ideas on why this is not working thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is you need to specify the parameters differently in your `call` method:

```
$this->call('GET', '/searchAvailability', array('keyword' => 'test product'));
```

Below is the implementation of `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::call` method:

```
/**
 * Call the given URI and return the Response.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  string  $uri
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @param  array   $files
 * @param  array   $server
 * @param  string  $content
 * @param  bool    $changeHistory
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function call()
{
    call_user_func_array(array($this->client, 'request'), func_get_args());

    return $this->client->getResponse();
}
```